# How to uninstall the FireFox simulator from browser

Tags: firefox, web

I would like to know how to uninstall the FireFox simulator from the Mozilla browser.

Because I have this message error on top of the window:

```
ReferenceError: debuggerSocketConnect is not defined
```

**P.S**: The simulator starts perfectly!

Comment: just remove it from extensions

Answer (score 0):

Enter **about:addons** in the URL bar.

Look for the Firefox OS versions you want to get rid of and **click the delete button**.